# What does suspicious behaviour mean?

Tags: hyrule-warriors, hyrule-warriors-legends

In Adventure Mode of Hyrule Warriors, sometimes this message pops up:

> [Character name] is behaving suspiciously! Act quickly!

What does this mean, exactly? When I defeat the character in question, it usually says, "You foiled the enemy plan", but I don't remember ever seeing a consequence when I just ignore them.

On the regular adventure map, this appears to be happening in most (if not all) missions where you have to defeat a given number of enemies as quickly as possible.

Comment: I believe this means the ally is about to go rogue and join an enemy team.

Comment: @Seiyria The characters I'm talking about are in the enemy team from the start, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These typically appear in the "Defeat {x} enemies!" missions, but also sometimes appear in other missions. If they are left undefeated for long enough, they will boost the morale of the enemy army.